# Concatenating strings from one file to another, without duplication

Tags: bash

There are two text files; *fileA* and *fileB*.

*fileB* contains strings that must be appended to *fileA*, but some strings may already exist in both files and we don't want to add duplicate lines

For example:

> fileA contents

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

> fileB contents

```
Line 2
Line 5
Line 6
```

From *fileB*, **Line 5** and **Line 6** would be appended to *fileA*.

I could write a C/C++ executable to do this, but I'd be calling it from a bash script. So, is there a fairly simple way to do this directly in bash?

To add a little context, Macs OS X uses ASL (Apple System Log) in replacement for the standard Linux Syslog. It has a config file (asl.conf) to which our product's installer adds lines to this file. An update must add new lines from a file, if they don't already exist in the config.

Comment: Look at `awk`. Deduplicating lines is a one-liner in awk and there are any number of questions on SO about doing that already. You'll need to output to a third file though.

Comment: Do you really want to remove the space?

Comment: @choroba, assuming you mean the space between, for example, "Line 5" thanks for pointing that out, it was a typo!

Comment: If fileA is small enough to fit in memory, you could just use awk: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];print;next}!($0 in a)' fileA fileB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
$ cat fileA fileB | sort -u
```

**Note**: this method can change the order of the lines.

To preserve the order of the lines, you can do:

```
#! /bin/sh
cat fileB | while read l; do
  ! grep -Fxq "$l" fileA && echo "$l" >> fileA
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but the lines are important.

Comment: I've just edit the answer adding a solution which preserves the line

Comment: Almost there, but it doesn't preserve the lines. Instead, it splits on white space, so any spaces creates a new line and also adds all lines.

Comment: Even with the edits, it adds lines which already exists in the first file. An example of a duplicated line is **? [A= Facility com.company.prog] [<= Level debug]  file /var/log/company/prog.log mode=0644 format=bsd**

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Calling `grep` for each line? Yuck.

Comment: Also, useless uses of `cat`; just use input redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %seen;
open my $A, '<', 'fileA' or die $!;
while (<$A>) {                    # Read line by line.
    print;                        # Print all lines from fileA.
    chomp;                        # Remove the trailing newline.
    $seen{$_} = 1;                # Remember the line.
}

open my $B, '<', 'fileB' or die $!;
while (<$B>) {
    chomp;
    print $_, "\n" unless $seen{$_}; # Print only if not seen!
}
```

Comment: Thanks @choroba, but this also duplicates lines.  
An example of a duplicated line is **? [A= Facility com.company.prog] [<= Level debug] file /var/log/company/prog.log mode=0644 format=bsd**

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: Oh, you want to deduplicate FileA as well? Then just check the update.

Comment: Not quite, I just didn't want to add a line, if it already existed.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: I don't understand then.

Comment: Sorry if I haven't made it clear; the code should not add any lines from fileB, if they already exist in fileA.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: That's what the old code did (rolled back). Maybe the line has a different whitespace somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, my perl knowledge is near non-existent; this doesn't actually write to the file, does it?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: No, it writes to the standard output, which you can redirect to a file (not the input one, though): `script.pl > output.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

```
fgrep -wvf file1 file2 >> file1
```

-w matches exact line.

-v invert.

-f match from file

```
bash$ cat file1
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
bash$ cat file2
Line 2
Line 5
Line 6

bash$ grep -wvf file1 file2
Line 5
Line 6
bash$
```

Comment: Thanks, but this appears to do nothing.

Comment: Did you check file1 content?

Comment: Yes, there's no change. If I redirect to a separate file with '>', the file is also blank.

Comment: bash$ grep -wvf file1 file2
Line 5
Line 6

I am getting output which I am appending to file1

Comment: I wonder if it's an OS X difference? Are you running this on Linux?

Comment: After testing, it appears that if fileA has a blank line (carriage return) at the end of the file, fgrep returns nothing in this case.

Comment: Ok, must be an OS X issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `awk` one-liner:

```
awk '/^ *$/ || !a[$0]++' fileA fileB > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt fileA
```

Comment: Updated to match all lines consisting solely of zero or more spaces. The regular expression can be adjusted as needed to accept your required definition of blank line.

Comment: I've checked again, it sort of works, but adds a lot of extra blank spaces.

Comment: Whoever downvoted the answer, please have the courtesy to explain why.